# Unity Raycasting 2D with Ray

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I want to cast a simple `Ray`, but if I put my `Ray` I want to cast in the Raycast-function Unity keeps insisting on a `Vector2` for the origin instead of accepting origin and direction of the ray. So to demonstrate in code:

```
void Start()
{
    RayUp = new Ray2D(transform.position, Vector2.up);
}


void Update()
{
    Physics2D.Raycast(RayUp, out WallUp, distance, WallFilter);
    Debug.DrawRay(RayUp);
}
```

Am I missing anything?
WallUp, distance and WallFilter are defined

Comment: I don't know how people can spot your issue if you don't show how the variables are declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not providing the correct inputs for Debug.DrawRay() and Raycast(). Please take a look at the [DrawRay documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) and [Raycast() documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html).
At a minimum you can do:

`Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.up);`

If you want to maintain consistancy from your original RayUp variable you can do:

`Physics2D.Raycast(RayUp.origin, RayUp.direction);
Debug.DrawRay(RayUp.origin, RayUp.direction);`